# Markov chain matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to modify this code in order to simulate 1000 individuals over 100 days. The code here is for just one individual. How would I modify this for a matrix with 1000 rows and 100 columns?

```
days<-100
CURstate<-1
state<-numeric(days)
for(i in 1:days){
  randomNum<-runif(1)
  if(CURstate==0){
    if(randomNum < .04){
      CURstate <- 1
    }else{
      CURstate <- 0
    }
  }else{
    if(randomNum < .11){
      CURstate<-0
    }else{
      CURstate<-1
    }
  }
  state[i]<-CURstate
}
```

I've tried doing this, but I keep getting an empty matrix back, and I have no idea why.

```
days<-100
PopMat<- matrix(0,nrow = 1000,ncol = days)
for(j in 1:nrow(PopMat)){
    state<- PopMat
    CURstate<-0
    for (i in 1:days)
      randomNum<-runif(1)
      if(CURstate==0){
       if(randomNum < .04){
          CURstate <- 1
       }else{
         CURstate <- 0
        }
      }else{
        if(randomNum < .11){
          CURstate<-0
       }else{
          CURstate<-1
        }
      }
      state[j, i]<-CURstate
    }
state
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one solution to your answer.

```
set.seed(1121)
gen_state <- function() {
  days <- 100
  CURstate <- 1
  state <- numeric(days)
  for (i in 1:days) {
    randomNum <- runif(1)
    if (CURstate == 0) {
      if (randomNum < .04) {
        CURstate <- 1
      } else{
        CURstate <- 0
      }
    } else{
      if (randomNum < .11) {
        CURstate <- 0
      } else{
        CURstate <- 1
      }
    }
    state[i] <- CURstate
  }
  return(state)
}

state_matrix <- t(replicate(1000,gen_state()))
```